# Parsing commands in a console application

Tags: c++, string, command

So my console application is based around commands, for example a user could enter "connect 127.0.0.1" and it would do stuff. I already am able to separate commands from arguments, but how would I make it call a function based on the command string, and have something to match commands to their string counterparts?

Comment: Should'nt that question go to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Why should it go there instead of here?

Comment: Because your question is not related to any source you are showing in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, and read commands from `std::cin`

You might want to declare a type for the vector of arguments.

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> vectarg_T;
```

declare a type for functions processing commands:

```
typedef std::function<void(vectarg_T)> commandprocess_T;
```

and have a map associating command names to their processors:

```
std::map<std::string,commandprocess_T> commandmap;
```

then fill that map at initialization time, e.g. using anonymous functions:

```
 commandmap["echo"] = [&](vectarg_T args){ 
    int cnt=0;
    for (auto& curarg: args) { 
      if (cnt++ > 0)   std::cout << ' ';
      std::cout << curarg;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
 };
```

If your question is about parsing program arguments (of `main`), use [getopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) and related functions. GNU libc [provides](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) also `argp_parse`.

**Consider** perhaps instead **embedding an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29)** in your program, e.g. embedding [GNU Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](http://lua.org/). But embedding an interpreter is an important architectural design decision and should be made early. Then your application becomes [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    map<string,string> commands;
    cout<<argc<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=argc/2;i++)
    {
        string cmd =argv[i*2-1];
        string param =argv[i*2];
        cout<<cmd<<endl;
    }
    string ip = commands["connect"];
    cout<<"are you want to connect "<<ip<<" ?";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to add an explanation on your code.